# Trigger Input Actions programmitcally in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I hope somebody can help me.
I am trying to trigger various input actions in the code of my Android app, for example the arrow keys of the keyboard. I am using the Unity Engine for that.

For this I use the new Input Manager.
First I have created a PlayerControls.cs and now Im trying to trigger the Input Actions in my Code, but I have no clue what I should do or what is missing.

```
private PlayerControls _playerControls;
private void Start()
{
 _playerControls = new PlayerControls();
 _playerControls.Player.Enable();
}
private void MoveLeft()
{
 //Don't know what to do here
 _playerControls.Player.LeftKey.performed += ctx => Debug.Log("Move Left");
}
```

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was auto-generated by com.unity.inputsystem:InputActionCodeGenerator
//     version 1.3.0
//     from Assets/PlayerControls.inputactions
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem.Utilities;

public partial class u/PlayerControls : IInputActionCollection2, IDisposable
{
 public InputActionAsset asset { get; }
 public u/PlayerControls()
    {
 asset = InputActionAsset.FromJson(@"{
 ""name"": ""PlayerControls"",
 ""maps"": [
        {
 ""name"": ""Player"",
 ""id"": ""9ad1d120-bd92-42dd-9357-3b98e01eaa3e"",
 ""actions"": [
                {
 ""name"": ""LeftKey"",
 ""type"": ""Button"",
 ""id"": ""079e35f9-2aaa-426a-bfc7-86c0d7ee2b09"",
 ""expectedControlType"": ""Button"",
 ""processors"": """",
 ""interactions"": ""Press(behavior=2)"",
 ""initialStateCheck"": false
                }
            ],
 ""bindings"": [
                {
 ""name"": """",
 ""id"": ""05c9439a-51d8-4e54-ae69-e627437e24bc"",
 ""path"": ""<Keyboard>/leftArrow"",
 ""interactions"": """",
 ""processors"": """",
 ""groups"": """",
 ""action"": ""LeftKey"",
 ""isComposite"": false,
 ""isPartOfComposite"": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
 ""controlSchemes"": []
}");
 // Player
 m_Player = asset.FindActionMap("Player", throwIfNotFound: true);
 m_Player_LeftKey = m_Player.FindAction("LeftKey", throwIfNotFound: true);
    }

 public void Dispose()
    {
 UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(asset);
    }

 public InputBinding? bindingMask
 {
 get => asset.bindingMask;
 set => asset.bindingMask = value;
    }

 public ReadOnlyArray<InputDevice>? devices
 {
 get => asset.devices;
 set => asset.devices = value;
    }

 public ReadOnlyArray<InputControlScheme> controlSchemes => asset.controlSchemes;

 public bool Contains(InputAction action)
    {
 return asset.Contains(action);
    }

 public IEnumerator<InputAction> GetEnumerator()
    {
 return asset.GetEnumerator();
    }

 IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
 return GetEnumerator();
    }

 public void Enable()
    {
 asset.Enable();
    }

 public void Disable()
    {
 asset.Disable();
    }
 public IEnumerable<InputBinding> bindings => asset.bindings;

 public InputAction FindAction(string actionNameOrId, bool throwIfNotFound = false)
    {
 return asset.FindAction(actionNameOrId, throwIfNotFound);
    }
 public int FindBinding(InputBinding bindingMask, out InputAction action)
    {
 return asset.FindBinding(bindingMask, out action);
    }

 // Player
 private readonly InputActionMap m_Player;
 private IPlayerActions m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface;
 private readonly InputAction m_Player_LeftKey;
 public struct PlayerActions
 {
 private u/PlayerControls m_Wrapper;
 public PlayerActions(@PlayerControls wrapper) { m_Wrapper = wrapper; }
 public InputAction u/LeftKey => m_Wrapper.m_Player_LeftKey;
 public InputActionMap Get() { return m_Wrapper.m_Player; }
 public void Enable() { Get().Enable(); }
 public void Disable() { Get().Disable(); }
 public bool enabled => Get().enabled;
 public static implicit operator InputActionMap(PlayerActions set) { return set.Get(); }
 public void SetCallbacks(IPlayerActions instance)
        {
 if (m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface != null)
            {
 u/LeftKey.started -= m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface.OnLeftKey;
 u/LeftKey.performed -= m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface.OnLeftKey;
 u/LeftKey.canceled -= m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface.OnLeftKey;
            }
 m_Wrapper.m_PlayerActionsCallbackInterface = instance;
 if (instance != null)
            {
 u/LeftKey.started += instance.OnLeftKey;
 u/LeftKey.performed += instance.OnLeftKey;
 u/LeftKey.canceled += instance.OnLeftKey;
            }
        }
    }
 public PlayerActions u/Player => new PlayerActions(this);
 public interface IPlayerActions
 {
 void OnLeftKey(InputAction.CallbackContext context);
    }
}
```

Comment: your code ` _playerControls.Player.LeftKey.performed += ctx => Debug.Log("Move Left");` only needs to be assigned once ..  Probably in the start.  Your MoveLeft is not being called from what you've shown

Comment: Maybe there's another way? Why do you need to emulate controls rather than just perform the action?

Comment: I am trying to control my main menu via gestures. The easiest way for me is just to trigger the left arrow button, because I do not know what exactly is triggered in the background